# Azure bot integration with skype for business ends in June 2019?

Tags: azure, botframework

We planned to do integration of azure bot with skype for business. We now see that Microsoft is going to stop the support of bot integration with skype for business by 30June2019. we would like to know if we get any extension of this and will be able to add new bots in skype for business channel.

Created azure bot and pending with skype for business integration.

Answer (score 1):

> Skype for Business channel in Bot Framework is being deprecated on June 30, 2019.
>   No new bots will be able to add Skype for Business channel after that date. Existing bots will continue to work until October 31, 2019. Microsoft Teams is the preferred communication tool from Microsoft.

[Source 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and [source 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview).

So no, you will not be able to add new bots, and there will be no extension as this has been publicised for a while now.

Comment: A comment would suffice, as the original question is off-topic (talking about product roadmap, deprecation dates, etc). Also, arguably falls under 'documentation' question type.